# Password recovery control fails to send mails

Tags: c#

I'm having windows vista and I checked that it does not have default virtual smtp in its IIS.

I used the local host with port 25 to send emails for my password recovery control but it is not working.

How can I send the email?

I got it working now. Here is my code:

```
PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Cancel = true; 
     PasswordRecovery1.MailDefinition.BodyFileName = "~/password.txt"; 
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); 
    smtp.EnableSsl = true; 
     smtp.Send(e.Message); 
}

<mailSettings> 
<smtp from="email@gmail.com">
 <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="email@gmail.com" password="xxxxx"/> </smtp>

 </mailSettings>
```

In password.txt file I wrote "You can return to the website by following login details. In password.txt file I wrote "You can return to the website by following login details.

```
<br>Username = <%Username%> </br>
<br>Password = <%password%>" </br>
```

Comment: We need more detail, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What exception do you get?  Is you checked the IIS isn't listening for SMTP connections, have you checked what _is_ listening?  Check the logs for your SMTP server and see if it's receiving the message and failing in some way internal to itself (and thus unrelated to the C# application).

Comment: Hell friends, I did lot of search to find the answer and finally got it. Now it is working fine. I did not install any free SMTP on the system. Instead I used the smtp.gmail.com as a server to send the mail.     protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        PasswordRecovery1.MailDefinition.BodyFileName = "~/password.txt";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(e.Message);
    }

Comment: and in web.config file I wrote  ( <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="myemail@gmail.com">
          <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="myemail@gmail.com" password="*******" />
      </smtp>
  </mailSettings>)

Comment: In password.txt file I wrote "You can return to the website by following login details.
Username = <%Username%>
Password = <%password%>"

Comment: In my IIS in control panel also i set the details as mentioned above and now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the scarce info provided ... I can only guess that your development mail server is not set up correctly. If you are sending using localhost then you will need to have smtp running and configured on the local IIS server. Why did you make sure this was off?

Comment: The error what I'm getting is this " No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25" I searched a lot for this error and got many answers like 1)the port 25 is blocking to send emails 2) try sending with gmail account and more. I tried that too but did not work. My SMTP is not configured in IIS i guess because when I ran telnet in command promt, it was showing me connection failed. How should I configure SMTP on my IIS with OS vista and how to send the email

Comment: This is a common error message when sending to a port that nothing is listening to or your credentials are refused. You say you made sure smtp on local IIS was off yet you are trying to email through localhost ... you need to configure smtp on your local host. There are plenty of articles on how to do this if you google it.

Comment: I used the following code    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="email@gmail.com">
          <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="email@gmail.com" password="xxxxx" />
      </smtp>
  </mailSettings>

Comment: protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

       // PasswordRecovery1.MailDefinition.BodyFileName = "~/PasswordRecoveryMail.txt";

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("any@any.com"));
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Subject = "Password recovery";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(msg);
    }

Comment: But the email what i get is completely blank

Comment: @user662417 - Please do not post code in your comments.  If you have code to post, edit your original question, much easier to deal with then.  Be sure you format the code and make it readable.